# Exception in thread StompReceiverThread-1

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, stomp

I'm having trouble with this error:

> Exception in thread StompReceiverThread-1 (most likely raised during
>   interpreter shutdown):

That is no traceback at all.. just that.
Usualy everything works fine but rarely it happens and then the action does not conclude.

Any tips?
My code:

```
class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn, request):
        self.conn = conn
        self.request = request
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        global WAITING_RESPONSE
        print('received an error: ' + message)
        WAITING_RESPONSE = False

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        global WAITING_RESPONSE
        try:
            msg = json.loads(message)
            if str(msg.get('transaction_id','')) == str(CURRENT_ID):
                printDebugLine('Queue response:'+str(message))
                manageQueueResponse(message,self.request)
                WAITING_RESPONSE = False
            self.conn.ack(headers['message-id'], '11')

        except stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException:
            print('Stomp error on message')
            sys.exit(3)
        except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR: %s' % str(e))
            sys.exit(3)

class Queue(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.host = xx
    self.port = xx
    self.login = xx
    self.passwd = xx
    self.request = {}
    self.start()

def start(self):
    try:
        self.conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(self.host, self.port)])
        self.conn.start()
        self.conn.connect(self.login, self.passwd, wait=True)
        self.conn.set_listener('xx', Listener(self.conn, self.request))
        self.conn.subscribe(destination='xx', id='xx', ack='xx')
    except stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException:
        print('ERROR: unable to connect')
        sys.exit(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR: %s' % str(e))
        sys.exit(3)

def send(self, data):
    global CURRENT_ID
    while WAITING_RESPONSE:
        time.time(0.1)

    try:
        CURRENT_ID = str(uuid.uuid4())
        data.update({'transaction_id': CURRENT_ID})
        b = json.dumps(data)
        self.request.update(data)
        printDebugLine('Queue request:'+str(data))
        self.conn.send(body=b, destination='xx')
        timeout(data,self.request,29)

    except stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException:
        print('ERROR: unable to connect')
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR: %s' % str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main program is exiting, the interpreter is cleaning up things, but the stomp receiver thread was not shutdown first.  The receiver thread goes to do something but basic modules are no longer available, so it gives an exception message, but cannot print a Traceback because that fuctionality is no longer available due to the program exiting.

Look at why the main program would be exiting.